# Does an intersecting $r$-family in $\mathbb{N}$ have a finite underlying base set?

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics

> Proof or counterexample: if $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{(r)}$ is intersecting then $\exists A\subseteq \mathbb{N}: A$ is finite and $\{F\cap A:F\in\mathcal F\}$ is intersecting.

I know this result is false for $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal P( \mathbb{N})$ because you can find a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and define $(F_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ by $F_i:=\{ f(i,j), f(j,i) :j\in\mathbb{N} \}$ so that $F_i\cap F_j=\{f(i,j),f(j,i)\}$ (or even make $f$ symmetric in its arguments to get a unique value in each singleton).

As I couldn't find a simpler construction, I suspect the result is true in the case of $r$-sets. I want to do something like taking an $A\in\mathcal F$ and considering sets $B,C$ such that $B\cap C$ is disjoint from $A$ (if none exist, we are done). Then include $B$ and find $D\cap E$ disjoint from $A\cup B$, and so on and it feels, based on instinct only, like after $r$ (or possibly $2^r$) iterations, we should be done.

Is the result true, and how can I prove it?

Comment: Let me try to guess. Is $\mathbb N^{(r)}$ your notation for the set of all $r$-element subsets of $\mathbb N$? Does "intersecting" mean "pairwise intersecting"? Am I close?

Comment: @bof Yes and yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to prove by induction the following stronger statement.

> If $\cal F$ and $\cal G$ are two families of sets of size at most $r$ and $s$, respectively, that *cross-intersect*, i.e., for all pair of sets $F\in \mathcal F, G\in\cal G$ we have $F\cap G\ne\emptyset$, then $\exists A\subseteq \mathbb{N}: A$ is finite and $\mathcal F_A=\{F\cap A \mid F\in\mathcal F\}$ and $\mathcal G_A=\{G\cap A \mid G\in\mathcal G\}$ are also cross-intersecting.

We prove by induction on $r+s$.
The claim is obviously true for $r=1$ or $s=1$ with $|A|=1$.
Pick an arbitrary $G_0\in \cal G$, and define for each non-empty $I\subset G_0$ the families $\mathcal F_I=\{F\setminus I\mid F\in\mathcal F, F\cap G_0=I\}$ and $\mathcal G_I=\{G\mid G\in\mathcal G, G\cap I=\emptyset\}$.
Since the size of sets in $\mathcal F_I$ is at most $r-1$, we can apply induction for the cross-intersecting $\mathcal F_I$ and $\mathcal G_I$ to obtain a set $A_I$ for them that satisfies the requirements.
Finally, take $A=G_0\cup \bigcup_{I\subset G_0} A_I$.

Note that this gives only $|A|<2^{r+s}$, or for your original problem $|A|<4^r$, but with a more careful analysis one can probably also get a polynomial bound.

Comment: Yes. It would be nice to find a reference for this fact. I seem to recall hearing it some 40 years ago, attributed to some Polish mathematican. Of course it could be and likely is much older.

Comment: I think the induction is on $r$ only, so the bound on $|A|$ given by the proof is actually a bit better (something like $2^r\cdot s$).

Answer (score 5):

The question has already been answered by @domotorp. The purpose of this additional answer is to provide some historical references.

A restatement of the result proved in the accepted answer is given by Andrzej Ehrenfeucht and Jan Mycielski, On families of intersecting sets, *J. Combin. Theory (Ser. A)* **17** (1974) 259–260 ([pdf](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82236099.pdf)), whom I quote:

> We shall prove first the following lemma which can be extracted from a proof of M. Całczyńska-Karlowicz [1] (see also [2] for a refinement of this lemma).
>
> LEMMA. *If $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are families of sets such that for all $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B$ we have $|A|\leqslant a$, $|B|\leqslant b$ and $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$, then there exists a finite set $S$ such that $A\cap B\cap S\ne\varnothing$ for all $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B$.*
>
> *Proof.* [. . . .]
>
> This simple proof is essentially due to Dana Scott and Ralph McKenzie (independently).

Reference [1] is to M. Całczyńska-Karlowicz, Theorem on families of finite sets, *Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Ser. Math. Astr. Phys.* **12** (1964), 87–89, to which I do not have access.

Reference [2] is to Andrzej Ehrenfeucht and Jan Mycielski, Interpolation of functions over a measure space and conjectures about memory, *J. Approx. Theory* **9** (1973) 218–236 ([pdf](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81931588.pdf)) from which I quote:

> Proving a conjecture of Kuratowski, Całczyńska-Karlowicz [2] found the following lemma.
>
> (6) For every positive integer $k$ there exists a positive integer $\kappa$ such that if $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are two collections of $k$-element sets, such that $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$ for every $A\in\mathbf A$ and $B\in\mathbf B$, then there exists a set $M$ with $\kappa$ elements at most such that $M\cap A\cap B\ne\varnothing$ for every $A\in\mathbf A$ and $B\in\mathbf B$.
>
> Theorem 24 proved below is a refinement of (6).
>
> Let $\kappa(k)$ be the smallest $\kappa$ satisfying (6) [. . .]
>
> [. . . .]
>
> THEOREM 24. $\ 2k+\binom{2k}k\leqslant\kappa(k+1)\leqslant(2k+1)4^k$.
>
> *Proof.* The first inequality is due to Frances Yao. [. . .]

Comment: Looks like I've been beaten to it by a couple of decades...